# Update Using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following query:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2) rno FROM @table
)
DELETE c1 FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON (c1.rno = c2.rno+1 OR c1.rno = c2.rno-1) AND c1.rid = c2.rid
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

Rather than delete I want to update a column, I have tried the following:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2) rno FROM @table
)
UPDATE cte
SET col3='Test'
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON (c1.rno = c2.rno+1 OR c1.rno = c2.rno-1) AND c1.rid = c2.rid
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

but get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'
```

Comment: You are missing the `FROM cte c1` in your update statement.  `UPDATE cte SET col3 = 'Test' FROM cte c1 -- etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `FROM` clause:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2) rno FROM @table
)
UPDATE c1
SET col3='Test'
FROM cte c1 -- MISSING HERE
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON (c1.rno = c2.rno+1 OR c1.rno = c2.rno-1) AND c1.rid = c2.rid
WHERE c2.id IS NULL;
```

You could also use `NOT EXISTS`, which [may perform better in SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) than `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2) rno FROM @table
)
UPDATE cte
SET col3='Test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM cte c2
                    WHERE (cte.rno = c2.rno+1 OR cte.rno = c2.rno-1) 
                    AND cte.rid = c2.rid);
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the reccommended changes to the query and used EXISTS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` goes in a `FROM` clause.  Do you mean this?

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1,col2) rno FROM @table
)
UPDATE c1
SET col3='Test'
FROM c1 LEFT JOIN
     cte c2
     ON (c1.rno = c2.rno+1 OR c1.rno = c2.rno-1) AND c1.rid = c2.rid
WHERE c2.id IS NULL;
```

Note I switched the update from `cte` to `c1`, because you are looking for no matches.  That query looks strange.  There may be an alternative way to accomplish what you want.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful in a question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is also correct, I marked the other as the answer as I used the improvement in query also.